# how does dlib get 128D vector from a aligned face? Is there any reference paper?

Tags: face-recognition, dlib

I have use [dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib) and [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) to do face recognition.

After detect face in a image,then align the face, then get the 128 vector from the face landmark(5 or 64 points)?

But how does dlib get the 128 vector ? I have see the [dilb code get 128 vector](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/tools/python/src/face_recognition.cpp), but I don't know what's the net means, is there any reference?

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to read that source and summarize it for you... but the author's email is in the file

Comment: I have found the question here http://blog.dlib.net/2017/02/high-quality-face-recognition-with-deep.html

Comment: I have found the question here http://blog.dlib.net/2017/02/high-quality-face-recognition-with-deep.html   `For those interested in the model details, this model is a ResNet network with 29 conv layers. It's essentially a version of the ResNet-34 network from the paper Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition by He, Zhang, Ren, and Sun with a few layers removed and the number of filters per layer reduced by half.`

Answer (score 1):

Reading FaceNet: A Unified Embedding for Face Recognition and Clustering will probably give you a good idea of how dlib and others generate an embedding of the face to later on do classification, clustering, etc

https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/app/1A_089.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I have see a good [blog: face recognition with deep learning](http://www.hackevolve.com/face-recognition-deep-learning/), which gives a good explain of dlib face recognition pipeline.

Comment: As you can see in that blog openface is a good starting point to understand how a pipeline would work. Don't hesitate to check it out:
https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/

Answer (score 0):

It is a regular CNN model. Dlib builds a ResNet model in the background. It is similar to prediction in a classification task.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib']
DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[0])
```

Verification function runs predictions for img1.jpg and img2.jpg. It actually feeds the pixels of those images as input to CNN models. [Here](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/tree/master/deepface/basemodels), you can see the model structures. All models except dlib are keras models. It is easy to read and understand. For example, VGGFace.py's baseModel function returns the CNN model.